# How to get Url inside Ajax in .JS file in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I need to `getUrl` from `Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('route/controller/action');` in Magento 2?
How to get this url inside `.js` file in Magento 2?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **`build`** function of **`mage/url`** class to generate url in js

```
define([
    'mage/url'
], function (urlBuilder) {

        return Component.extend({

            myFunction: function() {
                var url = urlBuilder.build("my/custom/path");
                console.log(url);
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: But i need url with key in admin.

Comment: I using this urlBuilder.build("") but my page URL concat as a site URL. That is why my ajax response not come properly.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
url:'<?php echo $this->getUrl('module/index/controller'); ?>
```

Comment: How to get url with key? Inside .JS File

Comment: url:'<?php echo $this->getUrl('module/index/controller'); ?>
?p='+pageno+',

Comment: @Ramanathan did it work for you ??

Comment: How this do it in  .js file?

Comment: save this code in hidden field`<input type="hidden" class="my_class" value="<?php echo $this->getUrl('module/index/controller'); ?>" />`  and then take value to js file.

Answer (score 0):

Here not given so I am adding another way also which actually helped me

Setting variable in phtml file:

```
<script>
require(['jquery','myscript'], function(jQuery){
...
...

window.myCustomAjaxUrl = '<?php echo $block->getUrl("frontname/ajax/method", array("order_id" => $order_id)) ?>';
});
</script>
```

Then use requirejs-config.js for alias and including myscript.js

```
var config = {
map: {
        '*': {
            myscript: 'js/myscript'
        }
    }
};
```

Then in myscript.js file,

```
define([
    "jquery",
], function (jquery) {
    "use strict";
    function myFunction(vars) {

       var ajaxUrl = window.myCustomAjaxUrl;
       jQuery.ajax({
                url: ajaxUrl,
                type: "POST",
                ...
                ... 
    }
```